# React native picker Android dynamically populated returns: Cannot Read propertie 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, undefined, picker

I'm trying to populate the Picker component of React Native with data brought from AsyncStorage. The code is as follows:

1. Load the data in componentWillMount:

   ```
   StorageManager.get('clients').then( (clients) => {
       this.setState({ clientsData: clients });
   });
   ```
2. RenderPicker method:

   ```
   let clientList = this.state.clientsData.map((client) => {
       const label = client.name;
       const value = client.company;
       return <Picker.Item label={label} value={value} />;
   });

   return (
      <Picker
         // Redux managed
         selectedValue={this.props.clientId}
         onValueChange={(itemValue) =>  
         // Redux managed
         this.props.invoiceFieldChanged({prop: 'clientId', value: itemValue}) }
      >
          <Picker.Item label="Select a client" value={0}/>
          {clientList}

      </Picker>);
   ```

The behaviour goes as expected when selecting a hardcoded option, such as "Select a Client", but when I'm trying to get any of the other options the following error appears:
[image]

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! Seems like you cannot hardcode an item and then use map. So the solution is to preprocess data and give a single array.